# How to solve the "Growing If Statement" problem?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

I've been doing some reading about design patterns and wanted some perspective.  Consider the following:

```
Dim objGruntWorker as IGruntWorker

if SomeCriteria then
   objGruntWorker = new GoFor()
else if SomeOtherCriteria then
   objGruntWorker = new Newb()
else if SomeCriteriaAndTheKitchenSink then
   objGruntWorker = new CubeRat()
end if

objGruntWorker.GetBreakfast()
system.threading.thread.sleep(GetMilliSecondsFromHours(4))
objGruntWorker.GetLunch()
```

The above code grows each time a new Criteria arises.  I've seen code like this all over the place and in ignorance wrote some of it myself.  How should this be solved?  Does this kind of anti-pattern have a more "formal" name?  Thanks for your help!

**Edit: Another consideration is I want to avoid having to recompile the existing implementations of `IGruntWorker` simply to add a new implementation.**

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromHours(4).Milliseconds`

Comment: Why do you think this is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Each time a new criteria comes up(A different version of the interface) then the code must be recompiled and that if-statement must be expanded.

Comment: You have to recompile anyway to have a new `GruntWorker` in you code, unless you compile it in a DLL and load it on runtime (but you'll have to compile that DLL too)... so I guess it's your `if/else if` that is really bugging you.

Comment: In an enterprise situation using multiple if-statements like that falls down on itself, especially when different entities are the factor by which the different implementations of logic are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET you could build it with reflection instead.  For example, if you were creating a plugin system then you would have a folder to drop plugin DLLs into.  Then your factory would look at the available DLLs, examine each one for the appropriate reflection attributes, then match those attributes against whatever string was passed in to decide which object to select and invoke.

This keeps you from having to recompile your main app, though you'll have to build your workers in other DLLs and then have a way to tell your factory which one to use.

Here's some really fast and dirty pseudo code to get the point across:

Assuming you have a DLL assembly called Workers.DLL

Set up an attribute called WorkerTypeAttribute with a string property called Name, and the constructor to be able to set that Name property.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class WorkerTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public WorkerTypeAttribute(string Name)
    {
        _name = Name;
    }
}
```

You'd then apply this attribute to any worker class that you've defined like:

```
[WorkerType("CogWorker")]
public class CogWorker : WorkerBase {}
```

Then in your app's worker factory you'd write code like:

```
 public void WorkerFactory(string WorkerType)
    {
        Assembly workers = Assembly.LoadFile("Workers.dll");
        foreach (Type wt in workers.GetTypes())
        { 
            WorkerTypeAttribute[] was = (WorkerTypeAttribute[])wt.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WorkerTypeAttribute), true);
            if (was.Count() == 1)
            {
                if (was[0].Name == WorkerType)
                { 
                    // Invoke the worker and do whatever to it here.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm sure there are other examples of how to do this out there, but if you need some more pointers, let me know.  The key is that all of your workers need to have a common parent or interface so that you can invoke them the same way.  (I.e. all of your workers need a common "Execute" method or something that can be called from the factory, or wherever you use the object.

Comment: You need a way of mapping some criteria to the actual workertype.  Other than that this code makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah, you still have to know when to select which worker.  But with the attributes you could provide a list to the user, for example, to have them pick which worker to use - or drive it via other logic in the system.

If you could sum up all of the data that you'd need to use to make the decision you could also pass that data object to each of the workers via reflection calls and call a method like "CanExecuteRequest(DataObject Data)"  This method would then let the worker decide whether it was supposed to handle the request or whether to just ignore it.

Comment: In other words:

Load the assembly
find the classes that are workers
send each one the data package via CanExecuteRequest()
Worker replies back with a true / false (or just does the request)
Call each worker who replied back true
Send back the results.

Your workers again would have to have a standard interface, and they would have to have some standard output that your main app will be able to trust and understand.

Comment: +25 I really like your answer.  Welcome to StackOverFlow

Comment: I like the plug-in part, but I'm not convinced that attributes are expressive enough.

Comment: I agree, I'd like to see a mapping layer to translate the conditions into the correct assembly reference.

Comment: Instead of using attributes, you can do: `if(wt.BaseType == typeof(IGruntWorker)) { ... }`

Comment: You still need a clever way of determining under which condition should a particular implementation be used that doesn't require constant maintenance of an if-statement.

Answer (score 7):

That sort of logic is often encapsulated using the [Factory method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  (See the ImageReaderFactory example under [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Encapsulation).)

Comment: as I understand, "factory method" is what he already has now. I'm not sure, that existing code can be more concise in any of .net languages except for F#. Pattern Matching would probably greatly help.

Comment: @Roman: It looks like he has this logic inline in the code where he's instantiating then using `objGruntWorker`, not in a separate method.

Comment: The factory method just refactors the problem into a another class.  Then that class has to change every time a new implementation is added of IGruntWorker.

Comment: @Achilles: Yes, that's the point of the factory method pattern, so you have this in one spot in your code that you know you need to maintain, instead of all over the place.

Answer (score 5):

The type of pattern that would suit the above solution would be the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). You have a situation where you don't need to know the concrete type of object you require, it just has to implement `IGruntWorker`. So you create a factory which takes in a criteria and based on that criteria you would return the specific `IGruntWorker` object. It is usually a good idea to map the criteria to some identifier i.e. an enumeration or constant for readability e.g.

```
public enum WorkerType
{
    Newbie,
    Average,
    Expert
}

public class WorkerFactory
{
    public static IGruntWorker GetWorker(WorkerType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case WorkerType.Newbie:
                 return new NewbieWorker();
            case WorkerType.Average:
                 return new AverageWorker();
            case WorkerType.Expert:
                 return new ExpertWorker();
        }
    }
}
```

So in your case you could have a small helper method that works out the correct type of Worker required based on the criteria. This could even be wrapped up in a read-only property which you just pass into the factory.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this solution is that it seems to refactor the problem into another class.  I still have a growing switch statement.

Comment: Yes but its clear and isolated as to its purpose - most people will recognize its a factory class, its constructs varying worker types and simplifies the use in application code.

Comment: It is easier to unit test at least. Just have to subclass the Factory class. Otherwise it is really tough to test code like your example.

Comment: have a look at how I implemented the factory using a IOC container (accepted answer).
That removes the If statements from your factory. You keep all the component-wiring logic in the IoC bootstrapper.
You could even potentially have this logic in an xml file...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965824/inject-different-repository-depending-on-a-querystring-derive-controller-and-in

Answer (score 5):

You could create Factories for each object type, and those factories could have a function that takes criterias as parameter and returns a IGruntWorker if the parameters are satisfied (or null otherwise).

You could then create a list of those factories and loop through them like (sorry I'm a c# guy):

```
Dim o as IGruntWorker;
foreach (IGruntWorkerFactory f in factories)
{
    o = f.Create(criterias);
    if (o != null)
        break;
}
```

When a new criteria is needed, you only add it to the list of factories, no need to modify the loop.

There are probably some more beautiful ways

My 2 cents

Comment: How about: `o = factories.Select(f => f.Create(criteria)).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

If you can define an object with a `checkCriteria` method, then you can **make this code table-driven.**  I don't know C#, so bear with me on the syntax:

```
public class WorkerFactory {
    IGruntWorker makeWorkerIfCriteria(criteria_parameters parms);
}

extern WorkerFactory worker_factories[];  /* table with factories in order */

IGruntWorker makeJustTheRightWorker(criteria_parameters actual_critera) {
  for (i = 0; i < worker_factories.length(); i++) {
    IGruntWorwer w = worker_factories[i].makeWorker(actual_criteria);
    if (!null(w)) return w;
  }
  --- grim error --- /* table not initiailized correctly */
}
```

Then some of the objects in the table look like this

```
public class MakeGoFor(critera_parameters cp) {
   if SomeCriteria then
      return new GoFor();
   else
      return NULL;
}
```

You can recompile the table in a separate module without having to recompile the selection code.  In fact, if you get ambitious, you could even build the table at run time based on command-line arguments or the contents of a file...

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a variant of the visitor pattern instead? Call it the factory visitor (perhaps)

excuse the pseudo-code, but my VB is rusty

```
Dim objGruntWorker as IGruntWorker

objGruntWorker = null

// all your objects implement IFactoryVisitor
Dim factory as IFactoryVisitor
while objGruntWorker == null
    factory = factoryCollection.GetNext 
    objGruntWorker = factory.TryBuild(...)
end

objGruntWorker.GetBreakfast()
system.threading.thread.sleep(GetMilliSecondsFromHours(4))
objGruntWorker.GetLunch()
```

Comment: Looks like what Mike Gleason jr Couturier suggested, but +1 for giving it a name.  Factory visitor.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as your most likely criteria are ordered first to allow the runtime to jump the rest of the cases, this is fine.

If your concern is just readability you could use the ternary operator or if the criteria evaluations are just ==, you could use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this pattern is fine, so long as your criteria and operations are single lines/method calls.  This is easy to read and accurately reflects your logic:

```
   if (ConditionOne())
   {
     BuildTheWidget();
   }
   else if (ConditionTwo())
   {
     RaiseTheAlarm();
   }
   else if (ConditionThree())
   {
      EverybodyGetsARaise();
   }
```

Even if there are 20 different conditions, it probably is an accurate reflection of some complex business logic of your application.

On the other hand, this is a readability disaster

```
if (  ((A && B) || C &&
      (D == F) || (F == A)))
{
   AA;
   BB;
   //200 lines of code
}
else if ( (A || D) && B)
{
  // 200 more lines
}
```

Comment: The issue is that it isn't extensible.  This single block of code has to know about all the types and what their criteria are.  If a new class is added, the code here has to reference it and add a new test.  I think a solution along the lines of what Mike Gleason jr Couturier suggested offers the best of both worlds.

Comment: That's my point.  I want to only compile the code that I need to, and "side-effect" compilations aren't any good in a large system.

Comment: One way to do this would be to have each child register itself with the base class in a static constructor.  This would let you plug a child in by adding a reference and then calling any static member.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of it depends on how predictable your 'conditions' are. Your 'growing IF' IS essentially a factory, and perhaps refactoring it out to its own method or class would help, but it may STILL be a growing-IF. If your conditions are things you cannot predict, like "if joe.is.on.fire" or "if x==2" or "if !shuttle.is.launched" then you're stuck with IF's.

One bad thing about these uber-IF's is the scope they may have over your application. That is, what all do you need to call/touch/check to determine which 'if' should be true? You might end up having tons of global cruft or lots of parameters to pass to your 'factory'. One thing I did a little while ago to help with this was implement a factory of sorts that contained an array of boolean-delegates (Func) and types. I would register boolean delegates and types at initialization-time, and iterate thru the list in the factory calling each delegate until I got a 'true' and then instantiated that type. That worked well for me becuase I was able to 'register' new conditions without editing the factory.

Just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I know your .NET but this is how I do something similar in a Java web application, where my 'if-thens' were growing....still requires a recompile but easy to add other actions or in your case grunt workers.

```
private HashMap actionMap = new HashMap();

actionMap.put("cubeRat", new CubeRatAction());
actionMap.put("newb", new NewbAction());
actionMap.put("goFor", new goForAction());
actionMap.put("other", new otherAction());

String op = request.getParameter("criteria");  // not sure how your criteria is passed in but this is through a parameter in my URL.
ControllerAction action = (ControllerAction) actionMap.get(op);
if (action != null) {
     action.GetBreakfast();
     action.Sleep();
     action.GetLunch();              
} else {
     String url = "views/errorMessage_v.jsp";
     String errMessage = "Operation '" + op + "' not valid for in '" + request.getServletPath() + "' !!";
     request.setAttribute("message", errMessage);
     request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to find a constructor of a given type and create the instance by the constructor. Of cause, constructors must follow certain pattern. In your example above, all are default constructors.