# Better way to instantiate different implementation according to value

Tags: c#

I am looking for help to see if there is any better way to write code. I need to instantiate different implementation based on some value, but somehow I feel that I can write xyz property in more generic way

Here is the simple representation of my code

```
public class A
{
    string p1;
    IEnumerable<B> b;
}

public interface Ix
{
    ...
}

public class x1 : Ix
{
     ...
}
public class x2 : Ix
{
    ...
}

public class C
{
    public C()
    {
        _a = GetA();
    }

    public List<Ix> xyz
    {
        get
        {
            if (_a.b == "sometype")
            {
                return _a.b.ToList().Select(r => new x1(r) as Ix).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return _a.b.ToList().Select(r => new x2(r) as Ix).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I can write xyz property in better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I need to instantiate different implementation based on some value"* - This is the [Factory Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10513086/119527).

Comment: It looks to me like the creation of this list is the responsibility of `A` and it could do this polymorphically rather than via a 'flag'.  Though the example is a bit contrived (and doesn''t compile), so it's a bit hard to tell.

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask this, you should probably try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making multiple lists for this, I suggest doing:

```
return _a.b.Select(r => new x1(r) as Ix).ToList();
```

but ideally, you'd do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Ix> xyz
{
    get
    {
        Func<..., Ix> factory = _a.b == "sometype" ? (r => new x1(r)) : (r => new x2(r));
        return _a.b.ToList().Select(factory);
    }
}
```