# Design pattern for translating data

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a C# project and I need to manage a local cache of data and present it on a GUI.

For example I have:

```
    public class DataFromOtherLibrary
```

Now I want make a class to help translate the information I need out of it

```
    public class MyDataModel
    {
            private DataFromOtherLibrary cache;
            public MyDataModel ( DataFromOtherLibrary Source)
            {
                    cache = Source;
            }
            public long Field1 { get { return cache.SomeField; } }
            public long Field2 { get { return cache.OtherFiled; } }
     }
```

Now the issue I have is I need to create a `MyDataModel` for every `DataFromOtherLibrary`  it would be nice to have a single translator class. I'm not sure how to do it and still implement properties (which I need to data-bind to).

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Sounds like you need a Factory that returns an `IMyDataModel`.  But that's somewhat a shot in the dark due to lack of information.

Comment: Agree, your goals are not clear

Comment: I also think you should use a Provider(Factory) Class which returns you a List with the MyDataModle Objects in it.

Comment: I think your after an [abstract factory pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern)?

Comment: As for me it seems like OP needs a proxy - class _with properties_ (because he needs to bind to them in UI library like WPF) which serves as a proxy for another class (DataFromOtherLibrary).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Provider with all your DataModels in it Like:

```
public class MyDataModelProvider
{
    public List<MyDataModel> DataModelList { get; set; }

    MyDataModelProvider()
    {
        loadDataModelList();
    }

    private void LoadDataModel()
    {
        foreach (Cachobject c in Cache)
        {
            this.DataModelList.Add(new MyDataModel(c.valueA,c.valueB));
        }
    }
}
```

and for this Provider you also need a Factory Like:

```
[Singleton(true)]
public class DataModelListProviderFactory
{
    private static DataModelListProvider dataListProvider;
    public DataModelListProvider getInstance()
    {
        if (dataListProvider == null)
        {
            dataListProvider = new DataModelListProvider();
           return dataListProvider;
        }
        else
            return dataListProvider;
    }
}
```

Because now you have a single Spot with all your DataModels and you only must recieve them once. You can also easily search the List for a specific Model if you have a case or you show all the Data in a View.

You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513086/why-use-abstract-factory-pattern-in-c-sharp) more about Factory Patterns.

Hope that helps.