# Why we need factory method pattern at all?

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern

I am learning `factory method` design pattern now, before that I learned `simple factory` pattern.
I thought `simple factory` is useful because it transfer the `if/else` control flow to factory so the purity of product can be reserved. And then I learned `factory method` pattern, and I thought it is complex and beautiful.

However, it occurred to me that there are no `if/else` control flow in `factory method` pattern any more, client know which product it will use and client choose corresponding factory.
For example

```
Factory factory = new SpecificFactory;
Product product = new SpecificProduct;
```

well, since client know which product they want to use(no `if/else` control), why just simple new SpecificProduct why need extra factory?

I searched for it but didn't find satisfying answer.
In fact, what I want to ask is like [Why do we need Abstract factory design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280170/why-do-we-need-abstract-factory-design-pattern) except for this one is factory method not abstract factory.

Comment: Still, you want your product Initialization to be encapsulated only in one place. the initialization may be much more than just calling the Constructor of the SpecificProduct class.

Comment: You don't need it until you'll need it. No answer makes much sense until you have the problem. Then you'll discover that your solution is actually a design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The Intent defined for this pattern in the GoF book is

> Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide
>   which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer
>   instantiation to subclasses.

There is still a conditional choice, but it's hidden in the client's inheritance structure.

The example used in the motivation section is of a framework for applications that can present multiple documents to the user.

In this example, there are two abstract classes `Application` and `Document`, which are subclassed as appropriate to (for instance) `DrawingApplication` and `DrawingDocument`.  `DrawingApplication` knows any document it creates should be a `DrawingDocument`, but the superclass `Application` doesn't.  So `CreateDocument` is made an abstract method in `Application` and implemented in subclasses to create the appropriate type of document.