# How to pass parameter to a class whose dependencies are wired through IoC container?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inversion-of-control

I have a class that works with a network via multiple resources. Its constructor receives arguments that are resolved at runtime by IoC container (StructureMap):

```
public NetworkWorker(IRetryService retryService, ILog log)
    { ... }
```

What I need is to control the number of resources this class uses on a use-case level - for example, client A need NetworkWorker instance that allows only one operation at a time, while client B need 10 ops at a time. 
Currently this number is hardcoded in the constructor. The only way I see is to add a method `void Configure(int resourceCount)` that each client of NetworkWorker would call with a different value. 
Or may be there's a better way I don't see? 
This class can do different things, but number of resources is required for every method call (`Get/Send/etc` methods).

P.S. is this a known technique (with a `Configure` method)? If it is, what's the name for it? smth like 'two-step initialization'?

Comment: related: stackoverflow.com/questions/10330308/… (has an example (the Func thing) of a generated factory with Structure Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll presume this NetworkWorker has multiple methods (otherwise you could just add a parameter to that single method).

You could use a factory pattern:

```
public interface INetworkWorkerFactory
{
    NetworkWorker Create(int numberOfResources);
}

public class NetworkWorkerFactory : INetworkWorkerFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    public NetworkWorkerFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public NewtorkWorker Create(int numberOfResources)
    {
        var retryService = _container.GetInstance<IRetryService>();
        var log = _container.GetInstance<ILog>();

        return new NewtorkWorker(retryService, log, numberOfResources);
    }
}
```

(or simply inject the required dependencies instead of the container)
and then simply

```
private readonly INetworkWorkerFactory _networkWorkerFactory;

public C(INetworkWorkerFactory networkWorkerFactory)
{
    _networkWorkerFactory = networkWorkerFactory;
}

public void M()
{
    var networkWorker = _networkWorkerFactory.Create(10);
}
```

Comment: yes, there are multiple methods - I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Autofac uses [delegate factories](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) for this.

Other containers have equivalent mechanisms of providing auto-generated [Abstract Factories](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) - @ploeh has an [awesome SO post aggregating examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2280289/11635).

The code in your question would look like so:

```
public delegate NetworkWorker Factory(IRetryService retryService);
public NetworkWorker(IRetryService retryService, ILog log)
{ ... }
```

A consumer would look like so (stolen from Alex's answer)

```
readonly NetworkWorker.Factory _networkWorkerFactory;

public C(NetworkWorker.Factory networkWorkerFactory)
{
    _networkWorkerFactory = networkWorkerFactory;
}

public void M()
{
    var networkWorker = _networkWorkerFactory(10);
    ...
}
```

The key difference is that you do not declare either an `interface` or an impl for the Abstract Factory - the `delegate` is the interface and Autofac 'just knows' to make the rest happen.

Another benefit of this approach (other than the code reduction) is that there's a natural path to transitioning the code to [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/))