# Should I inject an abstract factory or the value produced from the abstract factory into the consumer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Sometimes when I use dependency injection (Ninject shown here as an example), we will need to construct dependencies using parameters that are only available at run time.

This is where the [abstract factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2280289/465056) helps and I understand most of it.

However is there a reason why should/shouldn't we inject the value produced by the factory into the consumer directly instead?

Here's an example of it, assuming `Foo` can only be constructed by a run time `string` parameter and `IFooFactory` being the interface constructing `Foo`:

- Inject the abstract factory into the consumer

  ```
  public class ConsumerService : IConsumerService
  {
       private readonly IFooFactory _fooFactory;
       private readonly string _param;

       public Consumer(IFooFactory fooFactory, string param)
       {
           _fooFactory = fooFactory;
           _param = param;
       }

       public void PerformAction()
       {
           Foo foo = _fooFactory.Construct(_param);
           // Additional processing of foo
       }
  }

  public interface IFooFactory
  {
      Foo Construct(string param);
  }

  public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
  {
      public override void Load()
      {
          Bind<IConsumerService>()
              .To<ConsumerService>()
              .WithConstructorArgument("param", /* Some run time param */);
          Bind<IFooFactory>().To<FooFactory>();
      }
  }
  ```
- Rely on Ninject to **inject the value constructed by the `IFooFactory` into `Consumer` directly**

  ```
  public class Consumer
  {
       private readonly Foo _foo;

       public Consumer(Foo foo)
       {
           _foo = foo;
       }

       public void PerformAction()
       {
           // Additional processing of foo
       }
  }

  public interface IFooFactory
  {
      Foo Construct(string param);
  }

  public class MyNinjectModule : NinjectModule
  {
      public override void Load()
      {
          Bind<IConsumerService>()
              .To<ConsumerService>()
              .WithConstructorArgument("foo", 
                                       ctx => ctx.Kernel
                                                 .Get<IFooFactory>()
                                                 .Construct(/* Some run time param */);
      }
  }
  ```

Should I favour one over the other?

Comment: There's not much to it, but the latter is simpler in the consuming class, so I would go for that.

Comment: @stuartd The second version seems much easier to understand (without the Ninject bindings) and unit test too.