# Circular Dependency and Unity Container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a solution :

[image: solution]

- `Business` have a reference to `Business.Interfaces`, `DataAccess.Interfaces` and `Factory` (for resolve `IDataAccess` in `DataAccess.Interfaces`)
- `MainProject` have a reference to `Business.Interfaces` and `Factory` (for resolve `IBusiness` in `Business.Interfaces`)

My factory project use `Unity` for resolve dependencies. This project must have a reference to all others project except `MainProject` to access to constructors of concrete class and do mapping between class and interfaces.

But I don't add a reference to `Business` in `Factory` project because Visual Studio says to me :

***A reference to Business could not be added. Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency***

How to resolve this ?

Comment: I am not well familiar with Unity, but I think you should have the configurations (the registration of the classes) in the relevant project, not all in one project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andrei pointed out, when configuring an *application* to use DI, the *application* should be responsible for wiring up all of its dependencies in its [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

> A Composition Root is a (preferably) unique location in an application where modules are composed together.

Furthermore, the composition root should ***not*** be moved to an external library. Think of the composition root as a modern **code** replacement for a `.config` file. It is the *application* that is responsible for loading it and providing its contents to the dependent assemblies - the same is true for the Composition Root.

It is the Composition Root's job to *push* the dependencies down into the rest of the application. The dependent assemblies should not try to *pull* their own dependencies. It's called the *Hollywood principle* - "Don't call us, we'll call you". That said, it is also common to use the [abstract factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280170/why-do-we-need-abstract-factory-design-pattern) in conjunction with DI.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612) for a good visual representation of how it should work. Your application looks a *lot* like the first image - you should aim to make it like the second one. The application is *logically* setup in separate layers that depend on each other, but it is *physically* very flat.

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive answer. I use now a configuration file in my main project for describe the mapping between concrete class and interfaces. And it's my main project that has all references to other projects. `Factory` project read unity section in configuration and resolve dependency using `Unity`.

Comment: Oh, no that is not what I meant. Don't *actually* put your configuration into a `.config` file. That is an antiquated way to do DI (in fact, many containers have dropped support for it) - XML configuration is not type safe and is very brittle compared to configuring the container in code. But treat that code as if it *were* a `.config` file for the application.

Comment: Hum ok so how to do this actually ? My main project have a unityconfiguration.xml file with mapping between class and interfaces. My main project have also all references to others projects. How to change this ? My factory project doesn't have a reference to others projects and I don't want to add reference in this project. This project read configuration and resolve only dependencies

Comment: That is the situation that DI is made to avoid :). Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9503612/181087) again. You should make a section near the start of the launch of the `MainApplication` (inside of that application) with a composition root to configure DI. Your `MainApplication` can and ***should*** reference all of the dependent libraries, because it is that application that is responsible for composing them together. You [*never* should reuse the composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/), so there is no point in putting it in a library.

Comment: Your "factory project" sounds a bit smelly to me. If you have factories that inject runtime instances, I suggest you [read this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). If you have enough factories to fill a library, then it sounds like there is something wrong with the design (maybe not, but it could be the case). You should probably aim to eliminate that library.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to reorganise your project a little bit.

I would get rid of the `Factory` project completely. If all you do is to resolve dependencies then you can do that in your `MainProject` since this is the only one which will need to know how to map things.
`Business` shouldn't care about any concrete implementations, assuming all it does is to implement your business logic. Let it work with abstractions only, not concrete classes.

So in short, `Business` has dependencies on `Interfaces` projects only, `Factory` gone and all Unity mapping is done in `MainProject`. The `MainProject` is the only one which references all the other projects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I test this!